# Use Two NSSortDescriptor to filter array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort an array using the dictionary values "Name" and "Count". It would be Name alphabetically and split the names up into two groupd based on count.

bigger than 0

Smaller than Equal 0

My current implementation looks like this however it dose not split the groups up correctly.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortCountDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortCountDescriptor, sortNameDescriptor, nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [myArrayToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

return [sortedArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I would expect that your function would need to return two arrays (or an array of arrays); one array with zero counts, sorted by name and another array of non-zero counts, sorted by name.  You will need to filter into the two arrays first and then sort each of the two resulting arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by grouping you mean making them separate arrays then you need an NSPredicate instead of NSSortDescriptor for count key.

Try this (from what I understood the array is filled with instances of `NSDictionary` so I used casting to it. If that assumption is incorrect, the NSPredicate isn't hard to change to some other type or to be made more generic with KVC):

NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortNameDescriptor, nil];

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArrayToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortNameDescriptor]];

NSPredicate *zeroOrLessPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    if ([[((NSDictionary*)evaluatedObject) objectForKey:@"count"] integerValue] <= 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}];
NSArray *zeroOrLessArray = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:zeroOrLessPredicate];

NSPredicate *moreThanZeroPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:zeroOrLessPredicate];
NSArray *moreThanZeroArray = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:moreThanZeroPredicate];
```

Comment: Didn't see this answer arrive as I edited mine.  I agree with it.  The end result might be an array of the two arrays, and the outer or inner arrays might need to be mutable (implied by the OP).